# Python: retrieve  all properties of a class instance that uses the @property annotation

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there an easy way to retrieve all properties of a class instance that use @property or property methods?

I have seen examples that use vars but that does not work a class like:

```
class Test(object):
   CONSTANT='SKIP ME'

   def __init__(self):
       self.my = "my"
       self.__wrapper = {Test.CONSTANT : "wrapped value"}

   @property
   def wrapped_value(self):
       return self.__wrapper[Test.CONSTANT]
```

Desired output would be dictionary with key/value.

```
dict = {"my":  "my", 
        "wrapped_value": "wrapped value",
        "__wrapper" : <dict>
}
```

As an added plus is there a way to get it to skip class level variables?

Comment: I think the title should probably be edited as it's a bit misleading...you want all attributes of your class that are defined at an instance level?

Comment: Is that a better title ?

Comment: This so yes...and it feels like thats what I told you but I could be wrong because your example output doesnt match what you've asked.  __wrapper and my are not properties declared with the property decorator (also I'd say decorator not annotation because thats the proper terminology).

Comment: no, this is still confusing. `dir` lists all the attributes of a `Test` object, including `my`, `wrapped_value`, and `__wrapper`. So I don't understand why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: @senderle I am not sure what i was doing earlier, but dir is working now. I'll see if I can reproduce my old test case and if I can i will update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be this:

```
instance = Test()
dict((p, getattr(instance, p))
     for p in dir(instance)
     if p not in dir(Test) or isinstance(getattr(Test, p), property))
```

It yields:

```
{'_Test__wrapper': {'SKIP ME': 'wrapped value'}, 'wrapped_value': 'wrapped value', 'my': 'my'}
```

Comment: Thats fine, I was actually removing that variable manually.  This works.

Answer (score 4):

`property` is a class. Just test the class members to see if they're an instance of it.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   @property
...   def bar(self):
...     return self._bar
... 
>>> [x for x in Foo.__dict__ if isinstance(Foo.__dict__[x], property)]
['bar']
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> [x for x in foo.__class__.__dict__ if isinstance(foo.__class__.__dict__[x], property)]
['bar']
>>> dict((x, getattr(foo, x)) for x in foo.__class__.__dict__ if isinstance(foo.__class__.__dict__[x], property))
{'bar': 42}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will result in a dictionary of all properties of a class instance that use @property or property methods. It's similar to what others have said.

```
a = Test()
propdict = {} # or propdict = dict()

for attrname in dir(a.__class__):
     if isinstance(getattr(a.__class__, attrname), property):
         propdict[attrname] = getattr(a, attrname)
```

Then `propdict` would be `{'wrapped_value': 'wrapped value'}`, as `wrapped_value` is the only property of your `Test` class.